# SSH using Agent Forwarding with Windows Host OS, Vagrant Ubuntu Guest OS, and Keepass/Keeagent

Tags: ssh, virtualization, virtualbox, vagrant, ssh-agent

**Intent**: To be able to deploy to `lan-example.com` from any dev environment; whether it be directly from the virtual OS, or any single-OS system, or even over the internet using ONE SSH key stored in Keepass. I'm currently unable to do so from within Vagrant's OS unless I explicitly generate its own key and authorize it in each of my deployment servers. I believe the way to do what I want is through User Agent Forwarding, yes?

---

**Host OS**

- Windows 7 x64
- SSH key generated by puttygen: `C:\Users\Administrator\.ssh\id_rsa.ppk`
- Keepass with Keeagent storing my SSH key. Keeagent is set to "Agent" mode
- pageant.exe is installed but is not running
- If I wish to connect to outside/internal LAN servers using my key, Putty defers to Keeagent - Putty does not store the private key locations in its configuration.

C:\Users\Administrator.ssh\config

```
Host 192.168.55.2
  ForwardAgent yes
```

Vagrantfile

```
Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
  config.vm.network :private_network, ip: '192.168.55.2'
  config.ssh.forward_agent = true
  # Why would I need to set this if Keeagent is handling things?
  config.ssh.private_key_path = '~/.ssh/id_rsa_jake_mitchell.ppk'
end
```

---

**Guest OS (Vagrant)**

- Ubuntu x64
- 192.168.55.2, accessible through host only
- No SSH keys exist in `/home/vagrant/.ssh` (I removed them). The intent is to let User Agent Forwarding through the host OS (Keeagent) take care of using the key

---

**LAN Web Host (intranet websites)**

- Let's say its domain is `lan-example.com`
- It allows SSH passwordless login only using id_rsa.ppk public key
- 192.168.0.2
- User Agent Forwarding is enabled in sshd

---

**Problem:**

What works (using Host OS): Putty, connecting to `lan-example.com` without the need to explicitly reference the SSH key.

What doesn't work (using Guest OS): `ssh -v web-server@lan-example.com` as it shows that there aren't any keys to use.

I've noticed something about the [beta version of Keeagent](http://lechnology.com/software/keeagent/usage/options-and-settings/) that allows me to set the SSH_AUTH_SOCK. I've done so, and set up an NFS share that allows the guest OS to read the file; however this doesn't change anything. How does agent forwarding even work in this type of environment? What's different about Windows that causes this to fail?

Comment: It isn't clear to me what you are using to connect between the 'host' and 'client' systems.  Not all SSH clients are made the same.    Is your tool using plink, a cygwin ssh client, or something else?  Cygwin based ssh clients are not usually compatible with the Putty agent.

Comment: That's actually a very good question. The host OS (Windows) - I don't specifically know how Keeagent takes control as the SSH agent. As stated I have plink.exe installed but it's never active. What you can glean from this link is all I can add: http://lechnology.com/software/keeagent/. However with the client OS (Ubuntu) which resides inside of VirtualBox (via Vagrant setup) uses the standard open-ssh library. To be clear, my host OS uses Vagrant to load Ubuntu. I want to pass the credentials from the host OS to Ubuntu in the VM via Agent Forwarding.

Comment: And what looks to be their source: https://github.com/dlech/KeeAgent

Comment: I am not asking about keeagent.  I am not asking about what software is running on your Linux machine.  I am asking what program is making the SSH connection on the Windows host.

Comment: That's what I though I answered to. Ignoring the VM setup - Let's say I want to SFTP using FileZilla; Keeagent takes care of that. I don't have an SSH agent running other than Keeagent; though I don't know what process Keeagent creates/utilizes to do its thing. Maybe Keeagent temporarily utilizes plink, I don't know. I kept the process window open while I made a connection with FileZilla but I didn't see plink.exe show up anywhere. This is all on Windows (host OS).

Comment: `Let's say I want to SFTP using FileZilla; Keeagent takes care of that.` - This is where I think we are getting lost.  Keeagent/Pagent **only handles the authentication** for filezilla.  It isn't opening the tcp connection, handling the encryption, opening tunnel, or handle the sftp service.  There are several different SSH clients that will run on Windows.  Putty/Plink, filezilla, a few commercial ones, and the cygwin based ssh clients.  The cygwin based ssh clients cannot use cygwin.  You must run a cygwin based agent for.  So what are you using to using?  Not what authentication agent.

Comment: I have cygwin installed as well as plink. I take it you're saying that it's up to the application (Filezilla, SoureTree, Vagrant/Ubuntu) to choose which SSH agent it uses? How is the authorization executable communicating with the ssh-agent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sharing socket file through network file system won't work, as Windows socket and Linux socket are entirely different beasts — Linux inside VM would not know how to use Windows sockets. To make sure VM can utilize authentication agent on host, one needs to enable agent forwarding on **both** ssh client and server, then `ssh` into VM via host (not directly login on VM console).

Assuming:

1. SSH server agent forwarding setup is done, according to original post (I haven't used Vagrant so can't tell);
2. Keeagent setup is done and running (I have tried client mode but there are some problems dealing with non-RSA/DSA keys so agent mode is safer);

Under `putty` profile setup, tick option "Allow agent forwarding" under Connection → SSH → Auth in order to turn on agent forwarding for client. Alternatively, if Cygwin ssh is used on host, then there are 2 choices:

1. Install [ssh-pageant](https://github.com/cuviper/ssh-pageant) and make it start automatically with cygwin (in `~/.profile` and the like).
2. Specify desired Windows socket file location in Keeagent setup and set `$SSH_AUTH_SOCK` variable in cygwin to corresponding location.

To check if agent forwarding is working or not, ssh into VM and check the variable `$SSH_AUTH_SOCK`. If it's non-empty and pointing to a Linux socket file that exists, then everything is supposed to be fine. If the variable is empty then something is missing.